# Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document

Tags: c#, .net, google-chrome

So, I've basically read every StackOverflow question that's even closely related to this to no avail. Understandably, I suppose, since my issue involves .NET Forms in addition, so basically every fix is 100% inapplicable. Unfortunate, really.

Anyway, I've got a form that, when you click on of the buttons, the OnClick method on the backend runs a bit of code that looks like this:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.Charset = "";            
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
memory.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
Response.Flush();
Response.Close();
```

So, after building out a docx file, I return it to client. This works in every browser but Chrome. And it only *stopped* working in Chrome ~a month ago. Now, when you submit the form by clicking on that button, Chrome gripes about the response having the 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document' mime-type and refuses to download the file.